# Not able to run curl from command prompt windows 10 illegal port number globbing unmatched close brace error

Tags: curl

I have given escape quotes but still getting error

```
curl -u \"kr360:N8ffWqJyyrt56VyvkA08\" -X POST https:\\api-cloud.stack.com\app-automate\upload -F \"file=@D:\stackapk\debug-.apk\" -F \"data={\"custom_id\": "MyApp"}\"
```

error:

```
curl:(3) Illegal port number
curl:(3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in cloumn 6
```

could anyone suggest a solution

Comment: 1. all those backslashes seem totally wrong. 2. There's no URL in this command line. 3. `-X POST` is always wrong when -F is used.

Comment: thanks for ur comment im trying to upload an apk to server following is the orginial code given  curl -u "ktyu390:N8ffWqJuuFghYVyvkAp5" \
-X POST "https://api-cloud.stack.com/app/upload" \
-F "file=@/path/to/app/file/debug.apk"         but was getting error so i gave escape quotes kindly suggest an alternative

Answer (score 0):

I would *guess* that your command line should rather look like below (written in a single line, split up on multiple lines here for display purposes):

```
curl -u "kr360:N8ffWqJyyrt56VyvkA08"
https:\\api-cloud.stack.com\app-automate\upload
-F "file=@D:\stackapk\debug-.apk"
-F "data={\"custom_id\": \"MyApp\"}"
```

- dropped `-X POST`
- fixed the leading double-quotes around each argument to not be escaped
- escaped the double quotes around MyApp

(I seriously hope that is not your actual, real, credentials you're showing off to the world.)

Comment: @DanielStenberg...thanks for ur concern its dummy credential will try and let u know.thanks